# Using new operator without assignment

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, prism-4

Some of my projects use Unity and other IOC containers and I have seen a practice that some object is created without assignment like

```
new objectXXXX();
```

and this object is used by resolving the container on that type like

```
 _container = new UnityContainer();
var object= _container.Resolve<objectXXXX>();
```

Iam new to composition and Dependency injection in .NET.Is this correct way of writing code or I am missing some important concept.

Comment: This seems to me like an odd way of making the container instantiate the objects. Please provide more context so we can understand better

Comment: So some objects are created but are not then used? Is there something happening inside the constructor of these objects?

Comment: Can you also explain this statement: "this object is used by resolving the container on that type"?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I have provide details.Please check.

Comment: @TRS, the question is still not clear. I can't see how `new objectXXXX` is "used by resolving the container..."